Plotting a different data set
I am trying to plot the following list in which for each value of x point, we have three different values for the y point
list={{1,{1,2,3}},{2,{2,3,4}},{3,{5,6,7}};

Any hints for how to plot this? I tried ListPlot but it does not work well with the format of my list.
Thanks!

Clear[list];list = {{1, {1, 2, 3}}, {2, {2, 3, 4}}, {3, {5, 6, 7}}}; ListPlot[Thread /@ list]

Or Transpose, i.e., ListPlot[Transpose[Thread /@ list], Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
